# How to get a timestamp older than 1901

Tags: javascript, c++, python, timestamp

I'm trying to find to accurately count the number of seconds since Jan 1, 1850 to the present in a couple of languages (JavaScript, C++, and Python [don't even ask, I stopped asking these questions long ago]).

Problem is the platforms store timestamps as 32-bit signed integers, so I can't get a timestamp for dates older than 1901 to easily subtract the present timestamp from etc..  So how do I do what I want to do?

Comment: What precision do you need? For example, do you know that sometime number of seconds in a day is not `24*60*60`? [leap second](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leap_second)

Comment: As J.F. pointed out, this is a difficult question. Are you looking for the approximate answer ignoring special cases like leap days/years/periods?

Comment: The 1901 date seems misleading because 32 bits unsigned only gives a span (in seconds) of roughly 68 years, so you'd need several starting dates (along with the need to store at least two bits' worth of "startDateId") to cover the 1850-to-present period.

Comment: Alaska misses 11 days in 1867 http://www.skippizzi.com/a_mystery_missing_days.html

Comment: The question is about working around a 32-bit platform limitation. All these comments about how many seconds Alaska has in a Gregorian leap year are besides the point.

Comment: @mobrule: 32-bit part of the question is trivial, the part: "**accurately** count the number of seconds since Jan 1, 1850" is complex. My comments demonstrate why the latter part is complex.

Comment: The world did not exist before 1901, so don't worry about it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In python, there's the [datetime module](http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html#date-objects).  Specifically, the date class will help.

```
from datetime import date
print date(1850, 1, 1).weekday()  # 1, which is Tuesday 
# (Mon is 0)
```

**Edit**

Or, to your specific problem, working with timedelta will help out.

```
from datetime import datetime
td = datetime.now() - datetime(1850, 1, 1)
print (86400*td.days)+td.seconds  # seconds since then till now
```

Answer (score 3):

The portable, language-agnostic approach:

Step 1. Count the number of seconds between 01/01/1850 00:00 and 01/01/1901 00:00. Save this number somewhere (call it M)

Step 2. Use available language functionality to count the number of seconds between 01/01/1901 00:00 and whatever other date and time you want.

Step 3. Return the result from Step 2 + M. Remember to cast the result as a long integer if necessary.

Comment: taht will not work. The number of seconds between 01/01/1850 and 01/01/1901 will depend on the exact local of the point at which the time is taken. See: http://wikipedia/wiki/Gregorian_calendar for information about the adaption of the Calendar.

Answer (score 1):

Under WIN32, you can use **SystemTimeToFileTime**.

**FILETIME** is a 64-bit unsigned integer that counts the number of 100-nanosecond intervals since January 1, 1601 (UTC).

You can convert two timestamps to FILETIME. You can convert it to ULARGE_INTEGER (t.dwLowDateTime + t.dwHighDateTime << 32), and do regular arithmetics to measure the interval.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use **Date** objects instead of integers, at least to get a starting point.

```
function secondsSince(D){
 D= new Date(Date.parse(D));
 D.setUTCHours(0,0,0,0); 
 return Math.floor((new Date()-D)/1000);
}
```

//test with a date

var daystring='Jan 1, 1850', 
ss= secondsSince(daystring), 
diff= ss/(60*60*24*365.25);

alert('It has been '+ ss + 
' seconds since 00:00:00 (GMT) on ' + daystring + 
'\n\nThat is about '+diff.toFixed(2)+' years.');

Answer (score 0):

The egenix datetime is also worth looking at
http://www.egenix.com/products/python/mxBase/mxDateTime/